# Display logic, in the controller or the component?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

Say I have a `HomeController` and `Menu` (component).

I know that all of the props should come from the top down and be immutable. However, let's say I need the menu to display all links which are for a specific menu, should that filtering logic go in the menu or the controller?

Essentially this code:
`var items = menus.filter((item) => { item.name === 'main'; });`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what the right way is without further context:

**A. logic inside Menu (controller)**
If you have a complete menu-wrapper component (could be called 'menu-controller'), which can figure out internally which menu to display and in which structure, then the filter statement can be inside menu component.

All relevant info should then be passed as props to menu component.

Your statement (inside menu component) would then look something like:

```
var items = this.props.menus.filter((item) => { item.name === this.props.pagename; });
```

This would be a good way to avoid a bloated homecontroller, and to get a maintainable and *reusable* menu on each page.

**B. logic inside HomeController**
If the behavior of your menu is

- very specific to Home, and menu is not very much reusable across pages
- depends on various other Home parameters

Then it is probably better to stick to MVC principle that logic should be inside controller, and to keep components as pure (and dumb) as possible.
In that case:

- let HomeController select the right menu items to display, and build the menu structure.
- pass configured menu (`items`) to the menu component
- menu component simply renders the items it receives (without filters).